# How to add bottom constraint?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I am using Xcode 8.I add UIView in bottom.I see is perfect in storyboard.
[image: storyboard]

[image]

But when i run in simulator its doesn't look perfect. I don't know what the  problem is.

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear but did you try putting a constraint by Control+Click and dragging the mouse below the UI element and choosing the Vertical Spacing from Bottom Layout guide?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but in Xcode you add constraints by ctrl+click+drag from the view that needs a constraint to any other view (or the layout margins). This may look like this: 
[ctrl+click+drag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTErG.png)

On the size inspector (on the left side) you should then see all your constraints, so for example something like this: [example size inspector with four constraints defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kj6b3.png)

This is where you can also edit the properties of your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Look for several things that can go wrong

1. Your `UIVIewController's` auto resizing subview is turned off.
2. `UINavigationController's` translucent property goes wrong.
3. Your top view height is fixed & some of your constraint are breaking and bottom constraint is one of them.
4. Your constraint priority is low, so breaking the bottom constraint.

in the console look for following:

> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

this indicates, some of your constraint conflicting each other, fix it.

*If you insist on your question title*, how to add bottom constraint, then here it is

[image]

**NB::Hold the right click while dragging.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not using Autolayout.